# Dompdf with bootstrap not showing input values

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dompdf

When using Dompdf with Bootstrap css everything looks great, except for the inputs. The text inputs don't show the value inside and the checkboxes are not showing at all.
But if I remove the Bootstrap css everything works and values are printed.
What should I write in css for resolve this ?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: At the end I excluded Bootstrap css when generating the pdf. But now I have another problem... I uploaded my site to altervista and when I generate the pdf all the images go black and the checkboxes are replaced by question marks.

I've found out that it shoud be a font problem but no font seems to resolve this.

EDIT 2: I've reinstalled dompdf and changed the temp directory in a folder inside my project. Now the checkboxes are ok, but the images are always black with white foreground. I think this is caused by the transparency, but locally the images are displayed fine.

Comment: so it's the print style sheets, add your own with rules aimed at inputs, make sure inputs are shown with black text color, etc

Comment: make sure you're using the latest version of dompdf

Comment: I'm using the last version. Locally it works fine, only on altervista there are these problems...

Comment: have you checked permissions?

Comment: What permissions ?

Comment: I can't set file permissions on altervista...

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Look into dompdf requirements.

Comment: Ok thank you! Do you know a way to resolve this ?

Comment: Could be one of the image libraries available on your host. If transparency can be removed you can skip a lot of the image processing in dompdf by using JPG.